# psql load dump - invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to load 70GB of data (that I created from emails and attachments).

I am loading that dump file to a database now in another ubuntu server.

I already tried loading that dump in the same server and it worked. But now when I copied the dump file to new server and loading the dump, it is giving error:

```
 invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits 
 CONTEXT:  COPY tablename, line 1196, column file_column_name:
```

Comment: So what is the content of line 1196?

Comment: here it is - \x255044462d312e350d25e2e3cfd30d0a342030206f626a3c3c2f485b3239333536203935325d2f4c696e656172697a6564...